# How to dynamically add new partition in DolphinDB?

Tags: database, partition, dolphindb

I have a symbol-based value partition. It's mostly fixed symbol set. However, occasionally, I may add some new values to the symbol set. Can the system automatically add new values based on the data being loaded to the database without pre-define new values to the database schema?

Answer (score 0):

From version 0.97.0, DolphinDB accepts new values for VALUE partitioning as long as you set the parameter `newValuePartitionPolicy` to `add`